# link ajax response to smarty variables

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, smarty

I'm using `smarty` to separate the presentation from the business logic.
I have a form which contains a select box , an input text field(text to search for) and a button (search). Wen I click on the button I want to show the contacts array from my database without reloading my page again. So that I thought to use Ajax. But when using `ajax` within smarty, I have had major headaches with it the last few days... 
Smarty is only used when the page is actually loading (or reloaded), but not when an ajax request with `jQuery` (or other js frameworks) is answered so that I can't use ajax to send smarty variable to my form.
Is there any way to link smarty with ajax so that I can show the contacts array into an html table?
Can you help me to find a way  to show the list of my contacts after the searching on my page?

Answer (score 0):

Smarty is a php library and therefore cannot work on the client side.

If you want Smarty to parse some variables you will need to setup and parse a page before sending it as the response to the AJAX call and then have Javascript replace the html with the new code.